# Operating values in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, operation

I have this in PHP:

```
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {

}
```

Is it possible to operate these values in the string? like 128 + 250 + 220, using foreach ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings always follow that format, then yes. You could explode the strings into arrays:

```
$a = explode(' ', $string); // Now $a[0] contains the number
```

So, for your code:

```
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$total = 0;
foreach ($arreglo as $value) { // $key not necessary in this case
    $a = explode(' ', $value);
    $total += $a[0]; // PHP will take care of the type conversion
}
```

Or, if you are feeling creative:

```
$func = function($s) {
    $a = explode(' ', $s);
    return $a[0];
};

$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$numbers = array_map($func, $arreglo);
$total = array_sum($numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) 
{
   $expVal = explode(" ",$vaulue);
   $arr[$i] = $expVal[0]; //this array contains all your numbers 128, 250 etc 
}
$sum = 0;
foreach($arr[$i] as $num)
{
    $sum = $sum+$num
}
echo $sum; // your final sum result is here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with basic PHP functions:

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Working example:

```
<?php
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$str = implode(',', $arreglo);
$str = str_replace(' gigas', '', $str);
$n = explode(',', $str);
$count = array_sum($n);
echo $count; // Outouts 598
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the space between the numbers and letters are always there, you can do this

```
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$total = 0;
foreach ($arreglo as $value) {
    $total += strstr($value, " ", true);
}
echo "Total : $total"; // int(598)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
    $total=0;
    $arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
$total +=intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $value), 10);
}
echo $total;
    ?>
```

Demo:https://eval.in/463363

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) ,[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Working Example:

```
<?php
$data = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$data = array_map(function($value) { return str_replace(' gigas', '', $value); }, $data);
echo array_sum($data);
?>
```

[See it live here](https://eval.in/463362)

**Explanation:**

1) You have an array with string values. These values contain numbers also.

2) You need to sum all the numbers.

3) Use `array_map()` to replace all non-numeric characters from the string by using `str_replace()`.

4) Now, use array_sum() to sum total.

Answer (score 0):

If you want inline code

```
echo array_sum(str_replace(" gigas","",$arreglo));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use floatval() php function to get the float value from a string. Hope this helps.

```
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');

$sum=0;
foreach( $arreglo as $value ){
    $sum += floatval($value);
}

print $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$arreglo = array('128 gigas', '250 gigas', '220 gigas');
$sum=0;
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
$sum+=(int)$value;
}
echo $sum;
?>
```